# программа работает не до конца

Tags: c++

написал программу, которая из текста удаляет все символы, не являющиеся буквами, кроме пробелов. Если использовать string  - то всё работает, но если использовать char - то программа работает не полностью, т.е. не выводит буквы, стоящие после цифры/символа (например при вводе строки: edtrfy54 6bhjkj %^u выводит edtrfy, хотя должно: edtrfy bhjkj u).
в чем ошибка?

```
#include <cstring>

using namespace std; 

int main() {
    char s[255]; //Объявляем символьную строку (массив типа char)
    char str[100] = "";
    cout << "Enter a string:\n";
    cin.getline(s, 255, '\n'); //Вводим строку с клавиатуры
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) { //Пробегаем по строке циклом (слева направо)
        if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') ||
            ((s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') ||
            (s[i] == ' '))) { //Если символ латинская буква 
            str[i] += s[i]; //Записываем в новую строку символы, являющиеся буквами   
        }
    }
    cout << "Output of the program: " << str << "\n";
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен отдельный счётчик для второй строки, который будет увеличиваться только внутри `if`

Comment: `str[i] += s[i];` - ошибка тут.

Comment: 1) `char str[100] = "";` объявили массив из ста элементов, и все элементы инициализировали нулевым символом. 2) `str[i] += s[i];` в тех позициях, где находятся буквы/пробел записали в массив `str` сумму нулевого символа и кода буквы. В тех же позициях, где нет буквы/пробела в массиве `str` остался нулевой символ. 3) `cout << ... << str` вывели содержимое массива `str` до первого нулевого символа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал @EOF нужно добавить отдельный счетчик для для массива `str`, иначе он берет значение `i`-го индекса (комментарий @Stanislav Volodarskiy
) и как добавил @wololo в месте, где находится символ, неподходящий под условие будет стоять `'\0'`, соответственно конец строки. Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s[255]; //Объявляем символьную строку (массив типа char)
    char str[100] = "";
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin.getline(s, 255, '\n'); //Вводим строку с клавиатуры
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i) { //Пробегаем по строке циклом (слева направо) // добавил "j", как счетчик
        if (isalpha(s[i]) || (s[i]==' ')) { //Если символ латинская буква 
            str[j] += s[i]; //Записываем в новую строку символы, являющиеся буквами // ***str[j]
            ++j; // Если условие выполняется - увеличиваем j
        }
    }

    cout << "Output of the program: " << str << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я бы громоздкую проверку заменил на `if (isalpha(s[j]) || (s[j]==' '))`...

Comment: @Harry абсолютно согласен с `if (isalpha(s[j]) || (s[j]==' '))`

Comment: @Harry *только индекс `i`. Обновил в коде: `if (isalpha(s[i]) || (s[i]==' '))`